# Generating audio noise

Tags: python, audio, noise

I would like to generate audio background noise with python and saving it in an mp3. Ideally, I can also adjust the amplitude and the frequency. Is there a package that I can use for that?

THX
Lazloo

Comment: You just want to generate something like pink noise?

Comment: More white noise or black noise. But yes, I think in that direction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With scipy, you can save numpy array as a `.wav` file. You just need to generate a sequence of random samples from normal distribution with zero mean. `truncnorm` is truncated normal distribution, which makes sure the sample values are not too big or too small (`+- 2^16` in case of 16 bit `.wav` files)

```py
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

sample_rate = 44100
length_in_seconds = 3
amplitude = 11
noise = stats.truncnorm(-1, 1, scale=min(2**16, 2**amplitude)).rvs(sample_rate * length_in_seconds)
wavfile.write('noise.wav', sample_rate, noise.astype(np.int16))
```

Comment: I can see now that you set the amplitude of the generated noise signal to 2^n, (n<=16). But why not just any value up to 2^n ?

Comment: @HenrikR. It actually is any value up to 2^n, as exponential operator `**` in python accepts floats and the exponential function is a continuous function. You can set amplitude to 6.5234 if you want. As for why do i give the scale in the form 2^k and not direct number, it's because of the relationship between the amplitude and the loudness, the latter being in logarithmic relationship to the amplitude and it's easier to set. In the end it does not matter, you can also set the number directly, but it's just easier to choose from numbers up to 16 instead of up to 2^16.

Answer (score 0):

I regard this as a slight improvement of the answer from Mark, Feb 10, 2021:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy import stats

sample_rate = 44100
length_in_seconds = 3
noise = stats.truncnorm(-3, 3, scale = 0.3).rvs(size = sample_rate * length_in_seconds)
wavfile.write('noise float64 -3 +3 0.3).wav', sample_rate, noise)
```

The improvement is that I save float64 samples to the WAV-file instead of int16. That gives a better resolution but also a 4 times larger file. :-) You might choose float32 as a compromise.

Personally I use scale = 0.2 because after generating the noise file I import it in Audacity and use a high-pass and a low-pass filter, and for some reason - mentioned in https://forum.audacityteam.org/t/extracting-frequency-ranges-without-causing-amplification/42073/1 - this amplifies the signal. So if I use scale = 0.3 I get clipping.

Addition March 17th:

I have improved it a bit more. The result is a little better, in terms of a little less variation in the amount of signal at each frequency, if you use this new version:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy import stats
import numpy

sample_rate = 44100
length_in_seconds = 3
no_of_repetitions = 10
noise = numpy.array( stats.truncnorm(-1, 1, loc=0, scale=1).rvs(size = sample_rate * length_in_seconds * no_of_repetitions) )
if no_of_repetitions > 1:
    slices = []
    for i in range(no_of_repetitions):
        slices.append(
            numpy.array(noise[i * sample_rate * length_in_seconds:(i + 1) * sample_rate * length_in_seconds - 1]))
    added_up = numpy.zeros(len(slices[0]))
    for i in range(no_of_repetitions):
        added_up = added_up + slices[i]
else:
    added_up = noise
peak_value = numpy.max(numpy.abs(added_up))
numpy.abs(peak_value2))
added_up /= peak_value

wavfile.write('Quick noise float64 -1 +1 scale 1 rep 10.wav', sample_rate, added_up)
```

But I found another, more complex, method to create "noise", that gives a bit less variation in the 'amount' of signal at each frequency - see [How to generate noise in frequency range with numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933842/how-to-generate-noise-in-frequency-range-with-numpy/78173691#78173691)

Comment: `float64` WAVs are less commonly supported than `int16`. Especially for random noise the added resolution makes no difference.

Comment: I am not adding the "noise" to anything. I need it for a specific scientific purpose, so the precision is important to me. ;-) :-)

Comment: VLC Media Player has no problems playing the float64 WAV-file.

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't, since it's using ffmpeg's codecs under the hood (which can handle most anything).